# react-native-barcodescanner stop reading codes after first code read

Tags: react-native, barcode-scanner

By default react-native-barcodescanner continuously reads bar codes. I'd like it to read a bar code and then stop. How do I do that?

ZXing has the option to do this, [How to stop continuous scanning by zxing-android-embedded in Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31761832/how-to-stop-continuous-scanning-by-zxing-android-embedded-in-android), but react-native-barcodescanner seems to not expose this functionality.

Answer (score 0):

Use some kind of flag.

```
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.scanSuccess = false;
    ....
  }

  barcodeReceived(e) {
    if (this.scanSuccess) return;
    console.log("bar code detected", JSON.stringify(e));
    this.scanSuccess = true;
    .....
  }
```

Also check this example https://github.com/ideacreation/react-native-barcodescanner/blob/master/Examples/BarcodeScanner/index.android.js

Comment: This is a poor man's spin locker is there any guarantee that this is thread safe?

Answer (score 0):

You can stop like this. This code is from [here](https://www.thepolyglotdeveloper.com/2015/10/implement-a-barcode-scanner-using-react-native/). Go to link to see full example.

```
  onBarCodeRead: function(e) {
    this.setState({showCamera: false});
    AlertIOS.alert(
        "Barcode Found!",
        "Type: " + e.type + "\nData: " + e.data
    );
  }
```